# Building Android Apps

Tags: java, eclipse

```
Is there a way that I can take a program that works perfectly well in 
Eclipse/jGrasp and put it into Android Studio and make it run...
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;





     public class MathLab
        {
        public static double side, length, width, height, base1, base2, 
radius;

        public static void main (String args[])                         
        {   
            System.out.println("Geometry cheat sheet");
            enterData();
            display2DPerimeters();
            display2DAreas();
            display3DSurfaceAreas();
            display3DVolumes();
          //Geometry.           
        }

        public static void enterData()                      
        {   
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter  Side     ===>>  ");                                        
            side = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("Enter  Length   ===>>  ");                                        
            length = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("Enter  Width    ===>>  ");                                        
            width = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("Enter  Height   ===>>  ");                                        
            height = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("Enter  Base1    ===>>  ");                                        
            base1 = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("Enter  Base2    ===>>  ");                                        
            base2 = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("Enter  Radius   ===>>  ");                                        
            radius = input.nextDouble();
        }


        // Remove comments from the println statements below as you complete
```

each of 
            the methods of the Geometry class.
            // Leave comments in place for any methods that you have not 
    finished.

```
        public static void display2DPerimeters()                        
        {   
            System.out.println("\n\nPerimeters of 2D Shapes");







  System.out.println("______________________________________________");
            System.out.println("Square Perimeter:                 " + 
        Geometry.squarePerimeter(side));
           System.out.println("Pentagon Perimeter:               " + 
        Geometry.pentagonPerimeter(side));
            System.out.println("Hexagon Perimeter:                " + 
        Geometry.hexagonPerimeter(side));
            System.out.println("Octagon Perimeter:                " + 
        Geometry.octagonPerimeter(side));
            System.out.println("Rectangle Perimeter:              " + 
        Geometry.rectanglePerimeter(length,width));
            System.out.println("Circle Perimeter (circumference): " + 
        Geometry.circumference(radius));
        }//*/

        public static void display2DAreas()                         
        {   
            System.out.println("Areas of 2D Shapes");
            System.out.println("___________");
            System.out.println("Square Area:                      " + 
        Geometry.squareArea(side));
            System.out.println("Rectangle Area:                   " + 
        Geometry.rectangleArea(length,width));
            System.out.println("Parallelogram Area:               " + 
        Geometry.parallelogramArea(base1,height));
            System.out.println("Triangle Area:                    " + 
        Geometry.triangleArea(base1,height));       
            System.out.println("Trapezoid Area:                   " + 
        enter code hereGeometry.trapezoidArea(base1,base2,height));
            System.out.println("Hexagon Area:                     " + 
Geometry.hexagonArea(height));
            System.out.println("Circle Area:                      " + 
Geometry.circleArea(radius));
        }






        public static void display3DSurfaceAreas()                      
        {   
            System.out.println("Surface Areas of 3D Shapes");

System.out.println("=======================================");
            System.out.println("Cube Surface Area:                " + 
Geometry.cubeSurfaceArea(side));
            System.out.println("Square Prism Surface Area:        " + 
Geometry.squarePrismSurfaceArea(side,height));
            //System.out.println("Rectangular Prism Surface Area:   " + 
Geometry.rectangularPrismSurfaceArea(length,width,height));
            System.out.println("Sphere Surface Area:              " + 
Geometry.sphereSurfaceArea(radius));
        }

        public static void display3DVolumes()                       
        {   
            System.out.println("Volumes of 3D Shapes");

System.out.println("=====================================================");
            System.out.println("Cube Volume:                      " + 
Geometry.cubeVolume(side));
            System.out.println("Square Prism Volume:              " + 
Geometry.squarePrismVolume(side,height));
            System.out.println("Rectangular Prism Volume:         " + 
Geometry.rectangularPrismVolume(length,width,height));
            System.out.println("Pyramid Volume:                   " + 
Geometry.pyramidVolume(side,height,length));
            System.out.println("Cylinder Volume:                  " + 
Geometry.cylinderVolume(radius,height));
            //System.out.println("Cone Volume:                      " + 
Geometry.coneVolume(radius,height));
            //System.out.println("Sphere Volume:                    " + 
Geometry.sphereVolume(radius)); 
        }
    }




    class Geometry
    {
        // 2D Perimeters
       public static double squarePerimeter(double side){return 4 * side;} 
        public static double pentagonPerimeter(double side){return 5 * 
side;}
       public static double hexagonPerimeter(double side){return 6 * side;} 
        public static double octagonPerimeter(double side){return 8 * side;}
       public static double rectanglePerimeter(double l, double w){return 2 
/ (l * w);}
       public static double circumference(double r){return 2*Math.PI*r;}
        // 2D Areas
        public static double squareArea (double s){ return s * s; }
       public static double rectangleArea(double l, double w){return l * w;}
       public static double parallelogramArea(double b, double h){return b * 
h;}
       public static double triangleArea(double h, double b){return (h * 
b)/2;}
       public static double trapezoidArea(double a, double b, double h){ 
{return (a += b / 2)*h;}
       public static double hexagonArea(double a){return ((3* 
1.73205080757)/(2)) * a;}
       public static double circleArea(double r){return Math.PI*r*r;}
       // 3D Surface Areas
        public static double cubeSurfaceArea (double s) { return 6 * s * s; 
}
       public static double squarePrismSurfaceArea(double a, double h) 
{return 2 *(a * a) + 4 * a * h;}
       public static double sphereSurfaceArea(double r) {return 4 * Math.PI 
* (r * r);}
        // 3D Volumes
        public static double cubeVolume (double s){return s * s * s;}
        public static double squarePrismVolume(double a, double h){return (a 
* a) * h;}
       public static double rectangularPrismVolume(double w, double h, 
double l){return w * h * l;}
       public static double pyramidVolume(double l, double w, double h)
{return (l * w * h)/3;}
       public static double cylinderVolume(double r, double h){return 
Math.PI * (r * r) * h;}
    }
```

So Apparently Stack OverFlow wants me to add some context so I'll do my best, Main method is basically building other methods which we will use later to nevermind it went away!

Comment: "It went away" doesn't mean you should stop providing context in mid-sentence.  I'm voting to close because it's unclear what you're asking, and rating -1 because you couldn't be bothered to explain yourself or even format your post to be legible.

Comment: Ok sorry my bad, I have the answer now so thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot make a console application for Android. You can indeed use the source code from a project made in Eclipse but any console interaction with the user will not be displayed in the android application.

You need to make a GUI(Graphical User Interface) using Android Studio or any other IDE that supports Android Development.

[Android UI Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html)